# Column span with most recent JXTreeTable?

Tags: java, swingx, jxtreetable

I'm trying to have a particular cell span several columns, like this

[image: Column spanned JXTreeTable]

I can't figure it out though, [the forum](http://www.java.net/node/691190) I found that image has some code that doesn't work due to their being random variables I don't know how to get. From some other questions though it seems the way he did it was the wrong way anyway.

Does anyone know how to do this with the most recent version of SwingX, potentially with a new feature that's been added since 2009?

Comment: it's not supported: column structure is the same in every row (folders as well as leafs) and cell-spanning is not a feature, not in x/table nor xtreetable