# Span columns/merge cells with Netbeans' Swing Outline?

Tags: java, swing, jtreetable

How would I have a cell span multiple columns using Netbeans' Swing Outline? This is not in the documentation and I'm not sure where to even start.

Note that I'm [trying to do the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231662/column-span-with-most-recent-jxtreetable) with JXTreeTable, but no success so far

Comment: @GuillaumePolet See http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-swing-outline/org/netbeans/swing/outline/Outline.html . It comes as a dedicated maven package in the netbeans repo, so I decided to go ahead and give it a try

Comment: @GuillaumePolet: `Outline` may be seen [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692).

Comment: @TheLQ I think that not possible for J(X)TreeTable/Outline, maybe non_free components made by Jide (never used)